# Spritekit pinball flipper physics

Tags: ios, macos, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

I have a small problem.
I use this code:

```
override func keyDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    let s: String = String(self.returnChar(theEvent)!)
    switch(s){
    case "w":
        self.moveRightFlipper()
    default:
        println("default")
    }
}

func moveRightFlipper(){
    //do something
    //self.rotatePoint.zRotation += CGFloat(-0.50)
    self.busy = true
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if(self.busy == true && ticks < 5){
        self.rotatePoint.zRotation += CGFloat(-0.2)
        ticks++
    }
    else if(self.busy == true && ticks < 10){
        self.rotatePoint.zRotation += CGFloat(0.2)
        ticks++
    }
    if(ticks == 10){
        ticks = 0
        busy = false
    }
}
```

Everything works, only i have a small problem with the physics when I touch the w key the flipper doesn't always collide with the ball (I think it moves over it or something) and then the ball falls through the flipper, is their any solution to fix this?
Thank you very much

Comment: I have a side question: why are you using keyboard events instead of having the user just touch the flippers directly?

Comment: The keyboard events are just for testing on my mac, multi touching with a mouse is impossible and this is the fastest way (testing the methods as an osx application and converting the events to touch events for the final application)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `usesPreciseCollisionDetection` property on the physics body attached to the ball to `true`. I would also recommend using a SKAction to rotate your flipper, but I don't think it's necessary to make the collision work properly.